# Adding facebook 'like' widget to non-published website

Tags: facebook, widget, facebook-like

I am trying to add a facebook like button to my web-page, but I have not published my website yet. Facebook asks me to provide a URL, but the only URL I have is file://localhost/Users/.../Desktop/...kobe.html

Is there any way to add a like button to a page that is not hosted on the internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

facebook require backUrl link. localhost cannot be pinged back. so it is better to upload site and add facebook like . there are many free webhost you can upload there for testing.